# Cancan not able to edit or delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan

While using Cancan, I'm not able to edit or delete Comments - Comments are related to Jobs.

Cancan is working fine for Jobs but for Comments the edit and delete are not shown. Is this because the Comments are shown in Jobs?

```html
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :job
  belongs_to :user
end

                                  
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :jobcategory
 has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end
```

```html
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150522132410) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "comments", force: true do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "job_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "comments", ["job_id"], name: "index_comments_on_job_id", using: :btree
  add_index "comments", ["user_id"], name: "index_comments_on_user_id", using: :btree
```

```html
user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
        if user.admin?
            can :access, :rails_admin       # only allow admin users to access Rails Admin
            can :dashboard
            can :manage, :all
        else
            can :read, :all
            can [ :edit, :update, :destroy ], Comment do |comment|
                comment.try(:user_id) == user.id
            end

            can [ :edit, :update, :destroy ], Job do |job|
                job.user_id == user.id
            end
        can :create , Comment
        can :create , Job
        end
```

```html
- if can? :update, @comment
 = link_to "Edit", edit_job_comment_path(comment.job, comment)

- if can? :destroy, @comment
 = link_to "Delete", [comment.job, comment], method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }
```

```html
class JobsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :find_job, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
 before_action :authenticate_user!,except:[:index]

 def show
  @comments =Comment.where(job_id: @job)
 end
```

UPDATED:

```html
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :authenticate_user!

 def show
 end

 def create
  @job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
  @comment = @job.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:content))
  @comment.user_id = current_user.id if current_user
  @comment.save

  if @comment.save
   redirect_to job_path(@job)
  else
   render 'new'
  end
 end

 def edit
  @job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  authorize! :update, @comment
 end

 def update
  @job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
  @comment = @job.comments.find(params[:id])

  if @comment.update(params[:comment].permit(:comment))
   redirect_to job_path(@job)
  else
   render 'edit'
  end
  authorize! :update, @comment
 end

 def destroy
  @job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
  @comment = @job.comments.find(params[:id])
  @comment.destroy
  redirect_to job_path(@job)
  authorize! :destroy, @comment
 end
end
```

Comment: are you getting any specific error?

Comment: @bunty Hi, No i am not getting a error ,its just that i am not able to view the EDIT and DELETE in comments.

Comment: for which comments you are not able to see EDIT & DELETE options? i mean are you able to see for comment which create by yourself? bcoz as per the cancan defined ability, you can't see the comments which are created by other users.

Comment: @bunty I am not able to see EDIT & DELETE options which are created by me

Comment: in view page, what value `@comment` is holding? i think its needs to be just `comment`

Comment: @bunty Now I am able to view the EDIT & DELETE ,but when i try edit i am not able to update the edited comments.

Comment: are you facing any error? also form is submitting by http request or js/ajax?  is you are using http request what is redirecting_url you are giving?

Comment: @bunty No i am not facing any error , i am not using for ajax for comments but i am using for jobs model, I have updated the comments controller.

Comment: try with `redirect_to root_path` instead of `redirect_to job_path(@job)` in comments#update method

Comment: its giving me error :ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in JobsController#show  ,Couldn't find Job with 'id' , Its pointing to my Job controller where i have def find_job @job = Job.find(params[:id]) end

Comment: The edited comments is not being saved..

Comment: @bunty  The edited comments is not being saved.

Comment: is it possible for you to update code on github?

Comment: @bunty No i wont be able to update in github

Comment: @bunty i found my mistake thanks , can you post the answer you have given , so that i can vote for your answer, thanks

Comment: its ok.. what was mistake?

Comment: @bunty in CommentsController under def update permit(:comment) it should be permit(:content)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be your object is **comment** but you used **@comment**